# flutter connection problem on android via USB port

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I am on windows, I would like to test directly on android via USB.
my smartphone is an android 5.1 lollipop.

only I always get this error :

```
Unhandled Exception: [core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized.
```

- I looked everywhere on the internet, I followed all the indications without success.
- for information, everything works correctly with the web version

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.0, on Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.19043.1466], locale fr-FR)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability
```

- config firebase :

/android/app/google-service.json

- /android/build.graddle

https://github.com/memory660/flutter_auth_fire_bloc_cubit/blob/main/android/build.gradle

- /android/app/build.graddle

https://github.com/memory660/flutter_auth_fire_bloc_cubit/blob/main/android/app/build.gradle

- main.dart

https://github.com/memory660/flutter_auth_fire_bloc_cubit/blob/main/lib/main.dart

- android Studio -> Sdk Manager ->  [ok] android 5.1 Lollipop

Comment: Have you tried using the new firebase cli tool to scaffold your project??

Answer (score 0):

```
add firebase_core: ^1.13.1 package in your project.
initialize it before run app


Future<void> main() async {
  //Calls native code to initialize plugin
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Initializing firebase for project
  await Firebase.initializeApp();


  // Root widget`enter code here`
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```